# SCCM 2012 Full Inventory and Software Query

Tags: sccm, system-center

I need some help with a SCCM 2012 Query (Im not a SQL guy). Im Trying to create  a query to include Server Name, Total of Memory, Hard Drive(s) Letter and Space, Boot Up Time and the applications installed on the servers.

Here is what I have, is working but the report is generating Thousand of pages. Any other way or suggestion to generate what I need using a report or query?

> select distinct SMS_R_System.Name, SMS_R_System.IPAddresses,
>   SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM.Caption,
>   SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Manufacturer,
>   SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM.LastBootUpTime,
>   SMS_G_System_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE.ProductName,
>   SMS_G_System_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE.ProductVersion from  SMS_R_System
>   inner join SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM on
>   SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId
>   inner join SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM on
>   SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId
>   inner join SMS_G_System_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE on
>   SMS_G_System_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your query, I think this is a normal behavior. Supposing you have 100 computers, and each has 30 software. Then 3000(300*10) records will be returned back in all.

I recommend you divide the query into two parts, one includes Server Name, Total of Memory etc., and the other includes the applications installed on each server.

Besides, you could also use the built-in report "Products on a specific computer" to view the information.

\Monitoring\Overview\Reporting\Reports\Software - Companies and Products

Comment: Agreed, installed software will generate a ton of records for each box. Also possible is to place a drop down to select a machine name, and/or a text box to filter on a user input of a machine name.